# Basic If/Else if in C++

Tags: c++

I've just started learning C++ - and I have a Quick Question.

Using if/else if statements for more than one variable at a time. How do I have them separated?

Ex.

```
float a, b, c, d, e;

if (a > 0 && b > 0)
    cout << "blah blah";
else if (a > 0)
    cout << "blah blah a";
else if (b > 0)
    cout << "blah blah b";


if (c > 0 && d > 0)
    cout << "wowww";
else if (c > 0)
    cout << woww c";
else if (d > 0)
    cout << wowww d";
```

It errors, at the `else if (c>0)`.

How do I separate the two clauses?

Comment: @Mat: That should be an answer.  user1244445: Saying "it errors" isn't sufficient; you need to show us the actual error message.

Comment: thanks all. stupid mistakes. i'm learnin.

Answer (score 3):

In the `cout` statement, you have missed a double quote...

Answer (score 2):

You had missing quotation marks in some of your couts. This is what you want:

```
   float a, b, c, d, e;

    if (a > 0 && b > 0)
        cout << "blah blah" ;
    else if (a > 0)
        cout << "blah blah a" ;
    else if (b > 0)
         cout << "blah blah b" ;


    if (c > 0 && d > 0)
        cout << "wowww" ;
    else if (c > 0)
        cout << "woww c" ;
    else if (d > 0)
        cout << "wowww d" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, there is a double quote missing.

I would have written the code like this, for better readability, specially when not using braces after `if`:

```
float a, b, c, d, e;

if (a > 0 && b > 0)  cout << "blah blah";
else if (a > 0)      cout << "blah blah a";
else if (b > 0)      cout << "blah blah b";

if (c > 0 && d > 0)  cout << "wowww";
else if (c > 0)      cout << "woww c";
else if (d > 0)      cout << "wowww d";
```

Answer (score 1):

The `if`/`else` stuff is correct; however, you forgot quotes. The correct code looks like that:

```
 float a, b, c, d, e;

 if (a > 0 && b > 0) cout << "blah blah" ; else if (a > 0) cout << "blah blah a" ; else if (b > 0) cout << "blah blah b" ;

 if (c > 0 && d > 0) cout << "wowww" ; else if (c > 0) cout << "woww c" ; else if (d > 0) cout << "wowww d" ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed the double quote before `woww c` and `woww d`
@Mat have already commented ))